# Lazy Loading in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Is there any support in the SQLite libraries or frameworks for Android to lazy load? A common use case would be images stored in a SQL lite database. You can imagine getting a reference to a  SQLite backed POJO with getters for image resources and not wanting to fetch those resources until the accessor is invoked. This is supported in ORM's I have worked with in Java, but I have not found any good suggestions for lazy loading of SQLite data in Android.

Note, ***this is not a "lazy load in listview" question***. I am working on an implementation that is ***decoupled*** from any specific UI element.

Comment: What could be lazier than a Cursor, it doesn't load any data until you want to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: @dammason I would not consider that "lazy loading" in the sense that the term is used to communicate in application design. I am not going to pass a reference to a cursor all over my application.

Comment: Look at Hibernate's lazy loading for an example of what "lazy loading" usually refers to in ORM's

Comment: @darnmason A `Cursor` does not load data until the first access, but then it loads *all* records.

Comment: @CL. Are you _sure_ about that? The underlying entity in the SQLite library most certainly does process things lazily.

Comment: @DonalFellows And the Android framework uses [CursorWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow.html) to make it non-lazy.

Comment: "Is there any support in the SQLite libraries or frameworks for Android to lazy load?" -- not in the Android SDK. You are welcome to examine ORMLite, greendao, and [other ORM implementations for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/69) to see if any meet your needs. Note that storing images in BLOB columns isn't a common pattern, so you may be out of luck on that particular feature.